# Object id of ActionType.Send Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

`GameRequestContent.Builder()` needs to have `.setObjectId()` called, to use `ActionType.SEND` or `ActionType.ASKFOR`. Where do I get this objectId? 
In V2.8 we can create object but now as it is already created We have to use pre build objects and now this link

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=%7Bopen-graph-action-type-id%7D&version=v3.2

requires `Actiontype` id this is too much confusing 
Really need help if one can provide me solution to get the object id!